# How to create the proper array for Google Timeline from multiples array

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck trying to figure out how to create the proper array for a google 
timeline chart, like the advanced example:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#an-advanced-example

I have a function that do the queries and return the arrays needed but individually, the code:

```
$data0 = array();
$data1 = array();

$array = array();
$array[] = array("v" => $name . ' ' . $id);
$array[] = array("v" => (string) 'Process 1');
$array[] = array("v" => (string) $date1);
$array[] = array("v" => (string) $date2);
$data0[] = array("c" => $array);

$array = array();
$array[] = array("v" => $name . ' ' . $id);
$array[] = array("v" => (string) 'Process 2');
$array[] = array("v" => (string) $date3);
$array[] = array("v" => (string) $date4);
$data1[] = array("c" => $array);

return $data0;
//return array($data0,$data1) 
// array merge did not work for me in this scenario
```

for the graph i loop through a query result that return several values an i need to retrieve several dates from each value:

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {

list($data0,$data1) = ep_timeline($dbcon, $rows->id, $periodo);
$temp[] = $data0;
//$temp[] = $data0+$data1; <-- not work

}


$table['rows'] = $temp;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

The graph work if i use only one array, by ex. $data0, but i need to create one single array from both arrays, by example $data0 array is like this:

```
Array
(
[c] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [v] => Proyect 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [v] => Process 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,11)
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,14)
            )

    )

)
```

and $data1 looks like this:

```
Array
(
[c] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [v] => Proyect 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [v] => Process 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,14)
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,24)
            )

    )

)
```

the final array should look like this:

```
Array
(
[c] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [v] => Proyect 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [v] => Process 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,11)
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,14)
            )

    )

)    
Array
(
[c] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [v] => Proyect 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [v] => Process 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,14)
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [v] => Date(2017,7,24)
            )

    )

)
```

But i dont find a way to create it, any lights will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: Instead of `$data0[]=...` and `$data1[]=...`, just use `$data[]=...`

Comment: Yes, i tried that but only return the first part of the array ($data0 equivalent)

Comment: Oh you are right, i was cleaning the data array in each loop